# Is there a difference between starting a Python 3 generator with next(gen) and gen.send(None)?

Tags: python-3.x, yield, coroutine

When you create a Python 3 generator and start to run it right away. You get an error like:

```
TypeError: can't send non-None value to a just-started generator
```

And in order to going (send messages to it or get something form it) you first must call `__next__` on it: `next(gen)` or pass None to it `gen.send(None)`.

```py
def echo_back():
    while True:        
        r = yield
        print(r)

# gen is a <generator object echo_back at 0x103cc9240>
gen = echo_back()

# send anything that is not None and you get error below
# this is expected though
gen.send(1)

# TypeError: can't send non-None value to a just-started generator

# Either of the lines below will "put the generator in an active state"
# Don't need to use both
next(gen)
gen.send(None)

gen.send('Hello Stack Overflow')

# Prints: Hello Stack Overflow)
```

Both ways produce the same result (fire up the generator).

What is the difference, if any, between starting a generator with `next(gen)` as opposed to `gen.send(None)`?

Comment: I kind of understand the `next(gen)` need because I used generators with `for` of `while` loops. But the `gen.send(None) is seriously confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`generator.send()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator.send):

> When send() is called to start the generator, it must be called with None as the argument, because there is no yield expression that could receive the value.

Calling `next()` on the generator starts the execution until the first `yield` expression at which non-`None` values can be sent into it, which would become the value of that `yield` expression (e.g., `x = yield`).

Both `next(gen)` and `gen.send(None)` behave the same way (i.e., no difference in usage).

Comment: Then, because they are functionally the same (start a generator, getting it to the `yield` statement) I could choose to use `next(gen)` when the generator has a loop on it, and `gen.send(None)` otherwise...

Comment: @sargas: that's up to you but it makes no difference when starting the generator.